# Addresses from getSigners not funded with eth while testing with HardHat

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I'm trying to test a payable function in hardhat but the addresses i generate with ethers.getSigners() don't seem to have any eth on them. When I execute:

```
 [owner, add1, add2] = await ethers.getSigners();
provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
console.log(await provider.getBalance(add1.address));
```

the log gives me BigNumber { value: "0" }. And after that if i try to test my payable function it gives me:

```
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Not enough ETH'
```

Any idea what could be happening here? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to hardhat.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    ...
    defaultNetwork: 'hardhat',
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
          accountsBalance: "10000000000000000000000"
        },          
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: defaultNetwork was lacking property in my config, but typescript require `accounts` in `hardhat` like in answer of JJ McGregor

Answer (score 1):

With typescript:

```js
import { HardhatUserConfig } from 'hardhat/config';
import '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox';

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    solidity: '0.8.9',
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            accounts: {
                accountsBalance: '10000000000000000000000',
            },
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```